# Getting Cross-Origin issue while accessing API in Docker container but working fine in local

Tags: spring-boot, cors, dockerfile, microservices

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILavh.png)

I'm using Spring boot microservices API + dockerfile 
Kindly Help

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour.

You can add **@CrossOrigin** annotation to your controllers, or play a bit with Filters.

Comment: @CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/rest/") 
@Api(value = "CarDetails", description = "get sample values")
public class ItemController {
...
i have added that already, in local it is working file, but after deploying into docker, it shows **bold `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present`

Comment: are you using some reverse proxy such as nginx?

Comment: Yes , the find the below code for nginx.conf
server {
  listen 80;
  sendfile on;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   256;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  location / {   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}

Comment: You have to allow them also in nginx, take a look at [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/162429/how-do-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-in-nginx/).